# How to get a new version of a system file that I have messed up

Tags: filesystem

Is it possible to somehow get a new 'gnome-shell.css' file for the Adwaita theme.

The file is located in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` and I have messed mine up (I forgot to make a backup first).

Do I need to reinstall Gnome Shell completely to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I can think of is to download the [GNOME Shell .deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/gnome-shell_3.2.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb) package and extract the .css file from there, if you don't want to reinstall.

You can get the .deb for your architecture (the .css is platform independent really, but just in case) from this page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell

Next time you want to edit the .css file, make a backup :).

Comment: @Dave: the live Disk has it?

Answer (score 0):

For information only - since you have already got the file.

All the deb packages which you have downloaded should be still in your packages archive (unless you have been very diligent and have cleaned up your packages archive!)

Your packages archive is in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Thus for my version of gnome-shell (I'm using 32bit) I would extract the gnome-shell.css file directly from the archive deb file i.e.

```
cd ~/Downloads
dpkg --fsys-tarfile /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-shell_3.2.1-0ubuntu1_i386.deb | tar -xf - ./usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css
```

i.e. you pass the path + file name as a parameter as shown (all paths are relative so its `./usr/...` rather than `/usr/...` )